# Migrate work items from one organisation to another using vsts sync migrator

Tags: azure-devops, vsts-sync-migrator

I am trying to migrate custom work item from "ABC" from one project 'x' org to another project in 'y' organisation using the VSTS sync migrator.

While migrating I get this error:

> WorkItemRevisionReplayMigrationContext: ...the WITD named ABC is not in the list provided in the configuration.json under WorkItemTypeDefinitions. Add it to the list to enable migration of this work item type.

I was able to successfully migrate all other work items like user story, bug which already exist in ADO

Comment: Have you configured this specific work item type? You can choose how to handle it: you can create the WIT on the other end and map it to that or you can configure it to be mapped to a WIT that does exist.

Comment: That sounds like a really old version of the tool. The WorkItemRevisionReplayMigrationContext was dedicated over a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Please get the latest version of Migration Tools for Azure DevOps from the website below:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration

And check whether you have created WIT "ABC" in 'y' organization.